# mysql liking you and others

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

I wonder how to do this

[image]

I mean the "You and 19,389 others" How do you identify **YOU** from others. If a user is logged in and like a status or favorite a status or something like facebook. I wanna catch the "you" part. But I don't seemed to understand the logic behind it.

I'm using php, and jquery. How do you sort this out in sql? or is it really sql? how do you define the user from others?

If I'm doing it the wrong way or asking it the wrong way, please tell me the right way and the answer guys I badly need your help.

Comment: Because you == `$_SESSION['userid']`...

Comment: yeah but when it comes to outputting it how do that the easier, faster, and understandable way?

Comment: If your query is bringing back the details of all of the users, rather than just a count, it should be relatively trivial to determine whether or not one of them is the current user.

Comment: please guys show me some examples

Comment: don't make it more complex than it is; if all=20.000, then all-you is 19.999. So `$all = 20.000; if($user->loggedIn() && $user->likesThisPage()) { $phrase = 'You and '. $all-1 .' other people'; } else { $phrase = $all .' people like this'; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With only one query you can do like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS everybody, SUM(user_id = "your_user_id") AS you FROM fb_likes WHERE post_id = 4;
```

Then if `you` is bigger than zero print (in fact it must be 0 or 1 only):

```
You and [everybody - you] others like this.
```

Else

```
[everybody] like this.
```

Comment: this is awesome! Thanks I like it 'coz its fast and just one query. thanks well let me see

Answer (score 4):

First of all, when you click on "Like" there's an entry going inside a database assigned to the post. So let's say the post has ID 1234567890 so you going to see something like that inside your database table :

```
PostID      UserID
1234567890  54543534
1234567890  75231415
1234567890  78653421
1234567890  99653221

// Query example
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LikeTable WHERE PostID = 1234567890
// Return 4
```

First of all you count all like, there's 4 here.

After, you check if the UserID of the current logged user is in the database.

- Yes. He liked.
- No, he didn't liked.

Let's say we are user 54543534. **I am** in the database so I liked the post.

```
// Query example
SELECT PostID FROM LikeTable WHERE PostID = 1234567890 AND UserID = 54543534 LIMIT 1
// Return 1
```

Let's say we are user 8748977777. **I am NOT** in the database so I didn't liked the post.

```
// Query example
SELECT PostID FROM LikeTable WHERE PostID = 1234567890 AND UserID = 8748977777 LIMIT 1
// Return 0
```

So I say the IF/ELSE statement would be :

```
IF I liked 
    You and COUNT - 1 others like this.
ELSE
    COUNT like this. Click to like.
```

EDIT :

I think something like that will make the job :

```
SELECT COUNT(PostID) AS All, SUM(UserID = X) AS Liked FROM LikedTable WHERE PostID = X
```

Comment: I had the thought of the first one to query two different things. But I never had the thought of the count-1 thing its funny actually. Thanks so much but wouldn't it be slower to do it on a two queries? is there any advance way to do it?

Comment: You could do it in juste one query I guess... I'll edit and write a simple but I won't be tested.

Comment: its really fine. Thanks bro! but the logic is still there thankss

Comment: I added the query... almost the same as @jordeu lol

Answer (score 2):

Query for others:

```
SELECT COUNT(userid) FROM likeTable WHERE postid = $postid
```

Query for you:

```
SELECT COUNT(userid) FROM likeTable WHERE postid = $postid AND userid = $_SESSION['userid']
```

Then do:

```
if ($youCount == 1) {
    echo "Liked by you and " . $othersCount - 1 . " others";
}
else {
    echo "Liked by $othersCount people";
}
```

Comment: Those queries would need injection sanitized, don't use them verbatim

Comment: Yes I know that. But the logic seems quite understandable thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about optimal database schemas, but the way I see this is that every single like in Facebook terms is a node on FB's social object graph. Which probably means that every single like is an individual database record on some table. To count the number of likes, you just do a `COUNT` on like records associated with a post.

Now if that's the case, then it's trivial to include some identifying information on the like record on who performed it. Top-of-head, it would be an FK on a user's PK.

So if you're logged in on Facebook, it knows who you are and what your associated user ID is. For every post that it aggregates the likes to, it can counter-check your user ID to the user ID FKs on the likes, and determine which of those posts you've actually liked. Hence, it can conditionally display either `You and 14,000 others like this` or `14,001 like this`.

Answer (score 0):

Struggling to understand the question but I think you might be trying to do too much in one go.

Either Run two queries, one to check if 'you' (your session id etc.) are in the table that records this or pull the whole lot and use in_array or something similar to see if 'you' are in the list.